# How to sort an arrayList using compareTo

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, names, alphabetical

As the user is inputting names, I want the names to sort out instantly using a compareTo method and return them in alphabetical order as the user is entering the names.

I've tried using a forLoop method but don't understand exactly how the compareTo method actually works, I've looked everywhere and can't find exactly how to complete it.

```
public class sortNames
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner UI = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println("Enter words, stop with -1");
    while (true)
    {
        String input = UI.next();
        if(!input.equals("-1"))
        {
            names.add(input);
            System.out.println(names);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
 }
}
```

I would want the output to look something like this
(User enters) "Bob"
(should return) [Bob]
(User enters) "Ally" 
(should return) [Ally, Bob]
and so on with other names.

Comment: `Collections.sort(names)`

Comment: Don't forget about the cases of the arraylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `ArrayList`'s method `sort` :

```
names.sort(null);
```

The null parameter indicates that the natural ordering (`compareTo`) should be used.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case you should choose `TreeSet` as the data structure to store the names in sorted order. Use :

```
TreeSet<String> names = new TreeSet<String>();
```

Instead of :

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Will solve your problem.